# While frying the cheese garlic bread on a frying pan, can a silver foil prevent the base of bread from burning?

Tags: bread

Everytime I make cheesy garlic bread at home using a frying pan, the base of the bread turns black within few minutes. Can using a silver foil on the base prevent it from burning.

Comment: If you would eventually fry the garlic bread, you should probably substitute butter with other more heat resistant oil. But burnt garlic doesn't taste good, so you might need to do it with 2 steps: first make a toast with clarified butter then brush on some garlic butter?

Answer (score 3):

The foil will heat up to the same temperature as the pan, so no. You need to use a lower temperature to fry the bread if it turns black before it's cooked through.